# Rails if statement in the Javascript tag in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

So, I've got a bit of redundant code in one of my views:

```
- unless @event.start_time.nil? 
  :javascript
    $(function() {
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY, h:mm a'
      });
      $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date("#{@event.datepicker}");
    });
- else
  :javascript
    $(function() {
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY, h:mm a'
      });
    });
```

Basically, I'm using datetimepicker for one of my fields, and if the model has a value for that field, it will be appended. It would be cleaner if I could do something like this:

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      format: 'dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY, h:mm a'
    });
    - unless @event.start_time.nil?
      $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date("#{@event.datepicker}");
  });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the variable using Ruby/HAML and handle the conditional in JS?

```
:javascript

  $(function() {

    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      format: 'dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY, h:mm a'
    });

    var event_start_time_present = #{@event.start_time.present?};

    if (event_start_time_present) {
      $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date("#{@event.datepicker}");
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

We can embed a ruby code to check the condition `unless @event.start_time.nil?`, so the code will be:

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      format: 'dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY, h:mm a'
    });
    var validStartTime = "#{@event.start_time.present?}";
    if (validStartTime === 'true') {
      $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date("#{@event.datepicker}");
    }
  });
```